# Turn date format yyyymmdd into dd/mm/yyyy (PANDAS=

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe, where the column 'BIRTHDAY' is a column that has a date stored like yyyymmdd, something like this:

```
    id | BIRTHDAY 
1      | 19940514
2      | 19890627
3      | 19560101
```

I would like to turn the column BIRTHDAY into the format dd/mm/yyyy. So the final output would be something like:

```
    id | BIRTHDAY 
1      | 14/05/1994
2      | 27/06/1989
3      | 01/01/1956
```

How can I do it in Pandas?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and specify input and ouput format:

```
df['BIRTHDAY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BIRTHDAY'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print (df)
   id    BIRTHDAY
0   1  14/05/1994
1   2  27/06/1989
2   3  01/01/1956
```